# Core data after app store update

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data

we published an app in app store, recently added new entities to core data for next version update. At this point we are not worried about migration because all the user's data are stored in our server.

My question is will the update overwrite previous version of core data? if not, how to wipe out the older version?

Comment: have you changed the name of the sqlite file or it is same as in the previous version?

Comment: nope, just the same file with newly added entity thats all

Comment: Have you migrate it or you have modified the same xcdatamodel? If you haven't migrated then I think it may crash.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: yes, the update will overwrite the previous version of Core Data.

More precisely, it will migrate to the new data model and therefore adjust the sqlite store, creating new tables and fields as necessary. This version of the sqlite store will be incompatible with old versions. The old version of the sqlite store will be gone.

This implies that when you do a server sync, the applied logic to insert the new information into Core Data also has to be updated to reflect the new model.

Comment: But without migration is it possible to overwrite the previous version?

Comment: Yes, of course. I do not know why you would like to do that, but it is possible.

Comment: But, what I think that without migration it will try the match the schema between the previous version of sqlite file and the new version of xcdatamodel file, and it won't match hence it will crash. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: Correct. I would follow the conventional migration process to be on the save side. You can always engineer around it, but there is no good reason to do so.

Comment: @sanjitshaw You're right. If the schema between the previous version of file and the new version do not match it will crash. You can see the documentation by Apple  : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html